# i have a problem with exception "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"

Tags: java, arrays, loops

i have a problem with exception "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"
i wrote a program which have src array of 48 length then processes it to take each 6 indexes to another array using method arrayCopy and print each dst array
for me it works fine it prints each 6 indexes from the initial array but at the end i get an exception help please . the algorithm is just a test because i want to use the arrayCopy in another algorithm so i don't need suggestion to change the algorithm . i hope it is clear fair enough

```
  public static void main(String [] arg) 
        {   
            int[] src = new int[48];
            for(int j=0;j<src.length;j++)
            {
                src[j]=j+1;
                System.out.print(src[j]+" ");
            }   
            System.out.println();
            int[] dst = new int[6]; 
            int from=0;
            for(int i=0;i<src.length;i++)
            {
                System.arraycopy(src, from, dst, 0, 6); // Copies 6 indexes from src starting at from into dst
                from=from+6;
                print(dst); 
                System.out.println();
            }



            } 

        public static void print(int [] dst)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<dst.length;i++)
                System.out.print(dst[i]+" ");   
        }
```

Comment: Can you indicate exactly which line the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<src.length;i+=6)  // increment i by value 6
```

Or use `from` in the for expression:

```
for(int from=0; from<src.length; from+=6) {
    System.arraycopy(src, from, dst, 0, 6); 
    print(dst); 
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this looks like the solution, I think.

Comment: thank you it works , like to your answer and (star * Infinity)

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written it, on the last iteration of your loop from + 5 = 53 which is greater than 47 (therefore out of bounds of source).